# Convert SWF to PNG

Tags: php, flash, image

I'd like to be able to take a 1-frame SWF file and convert it to PNG through PHP. I'm okay with using command-line tools to get this done.

How could I go about doing this? I found [an ActiveX library](http://www.bytescout.com/swftoimage.html), but that seems like one too many layers. I also see that Gnash seems to have a [PNG output class](http://gnashdev.org/doc/html/classgnash_1_1PngImageOutput.html), but I can't figure out how to get to that from the command line without doing some deep coding of my own. Are there any other clever solutions available? Thanks!

**EDIT:** To clarify, this is not a one-time task I just want to be able to do once. I'd like to be able to have a PHP script perform this task on command. Thanks!

**Another EDIT:** One more clarification. This is not a situation in which, say, a user makes a drawing in Flash. I am downloading raw 1-frame SWF files, and want to save PNG copies in order to reduce download time. Is such a task possible? Thanks again!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can use [swftools](http://swftools.org). 
`swfrender file.swf -X pixelsize -Y pixelsize -o output.png`

If only one between -X -Y parameter is specified then proportions are respected

Comment: Odd. I had looked up swftools but somehow missed that particular tool that does exactly what I need. I'll check on that later today :)

Comment: Seems to work instantly - and to think I already had this installed! Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to work well with transparent backgrounds. Awesome tool though. One of our off shore developers is trying to suggest [SWFToVideo](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/swftovideosdk/swftovideosdk.html) but its $1000 for a license........ :( *sad face*

Comment: `swfrender` worked for my test case but sadly there is no option to select the zoom factor for rendering so I'm left with a way too small rendering where the text parts are illegible.

Answer (score 2):

See [From Google: Flash screenshot](http://danielmclaren.com/2008/03/use-javascript-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-flash-movie)

Comment: I'd prefer to start with server-side technologies, then try client-side, since there will always be malicious users out there. But thanks - I'll keep it in mind :)

Comment: The point of the article is that the screenshot is taken in Flash. You can do whatever you want with that image at that point.

Comment: PHP will let you write that png to the server using a filestream. It's going to use the same mechanism within Flash to encode the .png data, then you just send the byte array to your PHP method.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the type of swf's you have you could try FFmpeg from the command line:

```
ffmpeg -i movie.swf -f image2 -vcodec png movie%d.png
```

Comment: "[swf @ 0x9b822c0]Compressed SWF format not supported" - drat. Trying to Google a way out of this - apparently I should be able to build a tool that will decompress it...

Comment: Interesting. Now PNG is listed as one of ffmpeg's formats, but I get "could not find codec parameters" anyway. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: It looks like ffmpeg can only convert some swf formats, depending what they include.

Comment: @Lo'oris: That's why my answer says it might work depending on the type of .swf.

Comment: I used `swfcombine` to decompress the `swf` which made `avconv` (ffmpeg fork) accept it and produced two pngs but these where not renderings of the `swf` but just the two images contained in the `swf` so it seems more like an alternative`swfextract` to me.

Answer (score 1):

not really a server based solution, but i developed an AIR utility to convert SWF to PNG sequences: http://swfrenderer.kurst.co.uk/

Comment: This gets a +1 from me. After hours of searching and testing, this is the only thing that will work in reliably exporting an SWF to png sequence _with embedded movie clips_. Even the v1 AIR app still works perfectly with a CS6 SWF.