# FFMPEG and convert swf to image?

Tags: c++, linux, flash, ffmpeg, codec

I want to use ffmpeg to convert swf to png ,and I can't extract image from some kind of swf like: http://rapidshare.com/files/450953994/Movie1.swf

and I use this code in bat file(1.bat)

```
cws2fws Movie1.swf 3.swf
ffmpeg -i 3.swf -f image2 -vcodec png tese%d.png
```

Please help me!!
I only want to convert swf to image also suggestion other way sound helpful?

Comment: FFMPEG supports swf? Didn't know... where have you seen that?

Comment: @ronag: `$ ffmpeg -formats` returns ` DE swf Flash format`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mencoder doesn't support the compression `[swf @ 0xc230a0]Compressed SWF format not supported`. Give a try to http://www.swftools.org/download.html (I have tried myself after compiling swftools but without success). swfextract return

```
$ swfextract test.swf 
Objects in file test.swf:
[-i] 1 Shape: ID(s) 1
[-f] 1 Frame: ID(s) 0
```

No video, no sound, no png…

**Update −−−−−−**

After several errands, swfrender from swftools do the job. There is a non documented `pagerange` option. From `swfrender.c`:

```
int args_callback_option(char*name,char*val)
{
    if(!strcmp(name, "V")) {
        printf("swfrender - part of %s %s\n", PACKAGE, VERSION);
        exit(0);
    } else if(!strcmp(name, "o")) { 

    […]

    } else if(!strcmp(name, "p")) {
        pagerange = val;
        return 1;
    } else if(!strcmp(name, "s")) {

    […]

    return 0;
}
```

Now knowing that, you could do a shell script (here quick and dirty with bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
let count=1
swfinput=$1
while :
do
    output=`basename $swfinput .swf`$count.png
    swfrender $swfinput -p $count -o $output
    if [ ! -f $output ];
    then
        break
    fi
    echo swfrender $swfinput -p $count -o $output
    ((count++))
done
```

That's it…

Comment: I use cws2fws to decompress SWF file you mean converting with ffmpeg requiring different decompressing?

Comment: No, I have just tried an independent test starting from your sample file: 1. Decomp using swfcombine (provided by swftools); 2. Try to extract data with swfextract. The problem is that I'm only able to find shape data, no more. Cws2fws probably do the job correctly but there is no video to feed mencoder or ffmpeg, no png... I don't know what can be done with just shape. (You certainly notice I'm not a flash guru)

Comment: GOT IT!!!! swfrender is provided by swftools. `$ swfrender Movie1.swf -o output.png` and you get the first image of the animation in the png output. No need to decompress or extract… Now, is it sufficient for your need or would you get several png (i.e. the animation)?

Comment: Arrgghh… Just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001946/convert-swf-to-png . From your initial ffmpeg invokation, I assume you already know that one…

Comment: Really Thx, For you replays swfrender finish the job :D