# Have a link to swf. How to print this flash movie?

Tags: php, image, flash

My question is how print swf to image using php. But for best understanding I'll write introduction.

INTRODUCTION.
I think it's very interesting theme. On site X I found encrypted with AES128 swf. I need screenshot of this flash movie. I tried to download it and was happy when all was well done. But when I opened swf, it was not like on site.
Then I come back to site. On this swf elements are vanish and appear. When I click RightMouseBtn on swf on page and in context menu choose "print" (browser: Google Chrome 22) I got image with all elements displayed! That's what I need!

Question: How can I do the same action using PHP?

Comment: I found similar question: [Convert SWF to PNG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001946/convert-swf-to-png).  
But I think swfrender function wouldn't work on encrypted swf. I'll have the opportunity to test it in 2 hours.

Comment: And if it works there are one more question: could I get all elements displayed on saved by swftools image?

Comment: swftools didn't help. Using   `swfrender file.swf -X pixelsize -Y pixelsize -o output.png`  I got empty png file.

Answer (score 0):

What about using your keyboard *print screen* button ?

Comment: When I press Prt Scr I have image of swf at this moment: some elements are not displayed.